# Converting 3d images in meters to feet when exported to dxf

Tags: qgis, coordinates, 3d, autocad, dxf

In QGIS 2.10, I am using the raster calculator to convert a metric elevated raster to feet and then create 2 foot contours (no problem). But when I dxf it out and put it in CAD, I can get the contours to elevate correctly but the x,y is still in metric.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What units does your projection use?